# Cohomology of $\mathbb{S}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a corollary stating:

if X is contractible then  $H_0(X) = \mathbb{R}$ and $H_n(X) = \{0\}$ for $n>0$.

But $\mathbb{S}^n$ is contractible and $H_n(\mathbb{S}^n) = \mathbb{R}$.

I must be missing something.

Thank you!

Comment: It’s not contractible!

Comment: If contractible means any loop on, say $\mathbb{S}^2$, is homotopic to a point, that is true for $\mathbb{S}^2$ , isn't it ?

Comment: I think you are confusing contractible with simply connected.

Comment: Right! Thank you all, I will double check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{S}^n$ is not contractible.